# What is the use of private instance variables?

Tags: flutter, dart

Im studying dart and have this example code here that uses private instance variables:

```
class User {
String _first;
String _last;
  
String getFullName() {
return "$_first $_last";
}
}

main() {
User user = User();
user._first = "Bob";
user._last = "Smith";
var fullName = user.getFullName();
print(fullName);
}
```

The code seems to work just the same with or without underscores for the variables, so I'm really struggling to understand the true purpose of this and cant think of a real world example of when a protected variable could come in handy. Protected against what exactly since everyone is free to go into your code and tweak its implementation. Same goes for private methods. Hope someone can help me understand

Comment: The effect and importance is much more observable inter class Like in external packages and libraries. The internal state shouldn't be accessible for modification to the class using your library. In that case the users code is tightly coupled to your implementation and can break anytime you release any changes. Consistency is not guaranteed in such cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It prevents creation of unwanted and unintentional dependencies.**

```
class FooUtils{
  
  //Foo variables
  int _fooId;
  
  //Foo methods
  void _updateFooState(){
    
  }
  
  //Foo util methods for users
  void getUserDOB(int userId){
    //some logic
    _updateFooState();
  }
  
}

class UserClass{
  // User specific code 
  
}
```

When you write Utils or Libraries or Packages that others will use, you wouldn't want to create a dependency on your `class's` internal state.

By default class members are `public` if they are not marked with `_`. If these members are visible and modifiable, then your Application's state cannot be guaranteed to be consistent. In the above example `_fooId` is an internal implementation detail of `FooUtils` and it shouldn't be visible to anyone using `FooUtils` class. If modified externally it might result in erroneous output.

Comment: Oh I see. So this just helps end users avoid silly mistakes like changing variables/executing class methods they not supposed to, thus breaking the way the code was meant to work. Like if developing in flutter there is some widget implementation that sets a default protected `height` variable to equal half the screen height, if not protected then some user might try to specify a different height just because they see this as accessible, thus breaking the widget logic. Is this a correct way I can think about this?

Comment: Yes and also the user now depends on something they shouldn't. Like their application is now tied to the way our library works internally. We might decide tomorrow to change the internal implementation which might then break the users production application.

Comment: Cool now I finally get it, been struggling all day about this, thanks!

Comment: I had the same doubts when i started :)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that anybody could go into your code and tweak its implementation.
But we declare variables as protected or private to make our code better. These are called as access modifiers which allow you to restrict the variable access or control the access scope ofyour properties or methods.

When you declare a variable as public, it can be accessed from anywhere, within the class, outside of it and from any class that may extend it.

If you declare it as proctected then you cannot access it from outside the class but just from within it and any classes that my extend your parent class.

And when you declare it as private then you cannot access it from outside or from any extended classes but just from within the class that it is declared in.

Hope it will help you! :)

Comment: Sure. I'm interested with a simple example of how this makes things better, not saying it doesn't. Surely whoever writes some code wouldn't change variables randomly in a way that breaks their code, so why the need to protect.